# Android source folders

Tags: android, android-testing

I have an Android project which has a "src" source folder, and I also created a "test" source folder. The 2 folders have a package of the same name inside them. I added an activity to the test folder and set it as the main activity, but Android doesn't recognize it, even though as I said, its package name is identical to that of the "src" folder, which is also the package name of the application.
What am I missing? Do I have to use a separate project for testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my bad, I mispelled the activity name in the manifest file, and that's why it didn't work... Thanks to anyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

Remove test folder  from your project & create classes only in src folder because android recognize only src folder for compile application.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work as It only searches for files in the `src` folder. All your java files need to be placed in there. Instead of making two folders which have the same package name, try creating two packages inside the `src` folder and placing a class in each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your source folder is in the java build path.

(I am assuming that you are using Eclipse as your IDE)

Select your project, go to **Project** in the menu bar, then select **Properties**. In the windows that pops up, select **Java Build Path**, and make sure that your source folder is in the list, if not click on **Add Folder**, and select the source folder you want to add.